# Not working custom inline editor with jquery

Tags: jquery, inline-editing

i wrote a custom inline editor, and i have a problem with it. If i clcik on save button after then i can't edit it again, how can i fix it to work? And can you help me, to make it multiple? I mean, this work only with 1 div on a page, not more than 1.
Here is the code:

```
$(function() 
{
    var fut = false;
    $('.jq_edit').live('click', function() {
        if (fut==true){ } else {                                 
        var tartalom = $(this).html();
        $(this).html("<input type='text' value='"+tartalom+"'><input type='button' value='Save' class='save'>");
        fut=true;
        }
    });
        $('.save').live('click', function() {
            var mtartalom=$(this).prev().attr('value');
            $('.jq_edit').html(mtartalom);
            $('.jq_edit').append(" <span id='ok'><img src='accept.png'> Success</span>");
            $('#ok').delay(1500).fadeOut(500);
        });
});
```

And the html:

```
<body>
<div class="jq_edit">adsadasd</div>
</body>
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it multiple you have to change a lot, here my solution:

```
$(function() {
    $('.jq_edit').live('click', function() {
        // if success message is visible, remove it
        $(this).find('.ok').remove();

        // if already in input mode, return
        if ($(this).hasClass('inputMode')) {
            return true;
        }

        // change to input mode
        var tartalom = $(this).html();
        $(this)
            .empty()
            .append("<input type='text' value='" + tartalom + "'>")
            .append("<input type='button' value='Save' class='save'>")
            .addClass('inputMode');
    });

    $('.save').live('click', function() {
        // create success message
        var jSuccess = $("<span class='ok'> <img src='accept.png' /> Success</span>");

        // deactivate input mode
        $(this).parent()
            .html($(this).prev().val())
            .append(jSuccess)
            .removeClass('inputMode');

        // animate success message
        $(jSuccess).delay(1500).fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });

        // prevent jq_edit click handler
        return false;
    });
});
```

Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VTBY3/).

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the `if(fut==true)` check and it should work fine...what is happening is that once the `fut` variable is set to true, the inplace edit will never get executed. I'm still confused as to why you have that check in the first place...